# Error trying to get Flask Framework to work (building basic website)?

Tags: python, flask, pip

I'm trying to get a basic framework laid out for a website. The way a friend instructed me about this was to

1. install CURL (brew install curl)
2. use CURL to install pip (curl https://raw.github.com/pypa/pip/master/contrib/get-pip.py | sudo python)
3. pip install flask
4. python hello.py

where hello.py was just:

```
    from flask import Flask
    app = Flask(__name__)

    @app.route("/")
    def hello():
        return "Hello World!"

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        app.run()
```

as suggested by the Flask website.

Can someone tell me why I'm getting this error:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "hello.py", line 1, in <module>
      from flask import Flask
    ImportError: No module named flask
```

Thanks!

Comment: Did `pip install flask` run correctly?

Comment: @Blender not exactly actually. this is the error I got:                    `error: could not create '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/flask': Permission denied`

Comment: Try `sudo pip install flask`.

Comment: cool, I think it worked if this is what I was supposed to get (sorry I'm new at this stuff!) `* Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/`

Comment: That is correct. Now go to `http://127.0.0.1:5000/` with your browser.

Comment: Friends don't let friends use `sudo`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason that

> pip install...

did not work on it's own is that by default pip will try to install to the system wide module library.

> sudo pip install...

worked because sudo gives you the permissions to do just that.

The preferred approach, especially in development, is to use [virtualenv](http://www.virtualenv.org) which allows you to create a project specific module library which because it is created and maintained by you does not require system admin privileges.

There's a super short tutorial on using virtualenv [here](http://terse-words.blogspot.co.uk/2013/03/installing-git-and-virtualenv-on-linux.html).